# How to access a proxy set up through godaddy hosting

Tags: proxy, java

What port number and what IP address would the proxy server have if I installed a CGI script in the CGI folder of a hosting account through GoDaddy? (I'm using jmarshall's CGI proxy)

Would it just be the IP address pointing to the root of the site, or is there another pointing to the specific folder the cgi script is in (/cgi/hjjh.cgi)? Also is there a specific port? The purpose is to use a proxy through a java network connection.

Answer (score 1):

To use a CGI proxy, just navigate to the proxy page's URL. Access it the same way you access any CGI script. You don't need to, and can't, configure it in the browser. It's not that kind of proxy.